# (Expo dev client) Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I would like to know why this error "Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager." appears when I launch the development of my app with the dev client ( npx expo start --dev-client). the app works fine on Expo Go with the npx expo start command.

here are the installed dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.8",
    "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "expo": "~48.0.11",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-svg-uri": "^1.3.1",
    "moti": "^0.25.3",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.10"
  },
```

Do you know what could be causing the problem? Thank you.

I've already installed the dependency

```
react-native-safe-area-context
```

and reinstalled the dependencies

```
react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-vie
```

Comment: It seems that `RNCSafeAreaProvider` native implementation not  embedded within `expo-dev-client` you are using. Use EAS Build to generate a brand new Expo Dev Client with RNCSafeAreaProvider pre-compiled and embended.